# wait for multiple $.ajax calls with post load animations to finish

Tags: jquery

I had a function that called a few $.ajax posts using $.when which was working, but since I added some load delay animations to the success return of the $.ajax asyn call it isn't waiting for those in the $.when

```
    <script>
    function tableOne() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/cont/_ActionOne",
            type: "GET",
        })
         .done(function (partialViewResult) {
             var degree = 90;
             $(".type1").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degree + "deg)").delay(1250).queue(function () {
                 $("#tableOne").html(partialViewResult);
                 var degreex = 0;
                 $(".type1").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degreex + "deg)");
                 console.log("tableOne");
             })
         })
    }
</script>

<script>
    function tableTwo() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/cont/_ActionTwo",
            type: "GET",
        })
         .done(function (partialViewResult) {
             var degree = 90;
             $(".type2").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degree + "deg)").delay(1250).queue(function () {
                 $("#tableTwo").html(partialViewResult);
                 var degreex = 0;
                 $(".type2").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degreex + "deg)");
                 console.log("TableTwo");
             })
         })
    }
</script>

<script>
    function tableThree() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/cont/_ActionThree",
            type: "GET",
        })
         .done(function (partialViewResult) {
             var degree = 90;
             $(".type3").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degree + "deg)").delay(1250).queue(function () {
                 $("#tableThree").html(partialViewResult);
                 var degreex = 0;
                 $(".type3").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degreex + "deg)");
                 console.log("TableThree");
             })
         })
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.when(tableOne(), tableTwo(), tableThree()).then(function () {
                console.log("PostLoad");
                $('.CheckBox').attr('disabled', false);
        })
    });
</script>
```

the console.log("PostLoad") is fired before any of the other functions so this is hitting that before they are done.  I have tried wrapping the functions in the $.when with $.ajax but that hasn't made a difference.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable globally like window.allAJAX = 0;

Now add a `beforeSend:function(){}` section to your ajax calls and add 1 to this global variable w.dow.allAJAX.

On the `done()` call subtract the number with a 1 and check if it becomes 0. If it does that means all your ajax calls are complete and you can execute that part of code that you wanted to be executed after all ajax requests are complete.

Example:

```
window.allAJAX = 0;
function tableTwo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/cont/_ActionTwo",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend:function(){
            window.allAJAX++;
        }
    })
     .done(function (partialViewResult) {
         var degree = 90;
         $(".type2").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degree + "deg)").delay(1250).queue(function () {
             $("#tableTwo").html(partialViewResult);
             var degreex = 0;
             $(".type2").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degreex + "deg)");
             console.log("TableTwo");
         })
         window.allAJAX --;
         if(window.allAJAX === 0){
            //CALL YOUR FUNCTION
         }
     })
}
function tableThree() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/cont/_ActionThree",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend:function(){
            window.allAJAX++;
        }
    })
     .done(function (partialViewResult) {
         var degree = 90;
         $(".type3").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degree + "deg)").delay(1250).queue(function () {
             $("#tableThree").html(partialViewResult);
             var degreex = 0;
             $(".type3").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degreex + "deg)");
             console.log("TableThree");
         })
         window.allAJAX --;
         if(window.allAJAX === 0){
            //CALL YOUR FUNCTION
         }
     })
}
```

**OR**
If you already know how many ajax calls you will be making simply make window.allAJAX = 3 //(for three ajax calls).
Now simply subtract on each done().

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
function tableOne() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/cont/_ActionOne",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (partialViewResult) {
            var degree = 90;
            $(".type1").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degree + "deg)").delay(1250).queue(function () {
                $("#tableOne").html(partialViewResult);
                var degreex = 0;
                $(".type1").css("transform", "rotateY(" + degreex + "deg)");
                console.log("tableOne");
            });
        }
    });
}

....

$.when(tableOne(), tableTwo(), tableThree()).then(function () {
    console.log("PostLoad");
    $('.CheckBox').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Please further read the documentation of [jQuery `.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

Comment: I see, so you put the animation code in the $.Ajax? in the $.when should the calls to the functions be wrapped in $.ajax there? (will test your suggestion now)

Comment: The functions like `tableOne()` should return a `Deferred` object such as `$.ajax()` when you use them as arguments to `$.when()`. You can take a look at the documentation as already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I have, read it the best I could before posting here.  Tried putting the code in the $.ajax post on the individual functions like you suggested but the $.when instantly posts the then before the when is finished

Comment: I missed adding the return before the $.ajax... it doesn't fully work though.  2 of the 5 complete before it hits the .then but 3 of them were still loading

Comment: it seems random, sometimes one completes and sometimes none complete.

Comment: You can try another approach, which is shown as on the documentation. Something like `$.when(d1, d2, d3).done(function(v1, v2, v3) { ... })`.

Comment: that doesn't work either, in fact none load first doing it that way.

The issue I believe is the delay (which I need) is causing the html to load after a success message is giving and the elements I need to apply the watcher on aren't loaded at that time...

Comment: No it's not `d1.resolve(tableOne());`. I believe you need to study more regarding that. The parameter of the `resolve` method will be the data, not a `Deferred` object.